# What kind of Neural Networks can I use for forecasting?

Tags: machine-learning

I am thinking of using Neural Networks for forecasting. What kind of Neural Networks are suitable for this occasion? Are RNN suitable? LSTM? Thank you...

Comment: Depending on what you want to forecast, RNN (and LSTM in particular) may be a good choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with dyukha that it depends. LSTM have shown good performance on forecasting on different tasks: [this approach](https://eng.uber.com/m4-forecasting-competition/) with LSTM won the M4 competition, Amazon uses LSTM for forecasting as well [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.04110), [blog](https://medium.com/@julsimon/predicting-world-temperature-with-time-series-and-deepar-on-amazon-sagemaker-e371cf94ddb5).

Implementing such approaches from scratch is doable but can be a bit tricky if you are not familiar with neural network framework. However, you can use directly implementations from [Gluon-ts](https://github.com/awslabs/gluon-ts) which contains different type of neural network architecture (LSTM, convolution, feedforward, attention, etc) that you can try to see which one works best with your data.

Comment: GRUs do something more?

Comment: What software should I use in order to train and use a model of RNN, LSTM in an embedded device such as Raspberry Pi 4B/3B+ ?? Thank you

Comment: It is better to ask separate questions for separate topics. You can try mxnet for Rpi https://gist.github.com/aaronmarkham/b3d0c715abca92ccc4b79ed0f19d1916 where gluonts might work if you need to mode time series.